# Is there way to implement textbox autocompletion like in general commandline?

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete, textbox

Let me ellaborate a little.
My work environment we have an inhouse developed html/javasript interface where we can configurate a the behavior of some machines (robots :P )
In this html page i can give commands to the unit like:
/machineX/robotY/commandxyz
ofcourse machine is not always machine(1-3) and robot is not always robot.
Can you reccommend me a solution where I (and the enduser) can type in commands fast as in commandline, simple autocomplate won't work because we have a lot of commands, and machines. So basicly what I am looking for is a multi level autocomplete, first selecting the avaible machines, than the avaible commands, then the avaible parameters...
Thank you! :)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Can you please have a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask We need to see your code. Thanks.

Comment: Well, I only need a library recommendation, I don't think code is necessary.